# How do I fix mismatching dependencies in my Cargo file to work around native library collisions?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-rocket

I'm setting up a Rust server with [Rocket](https://rocket.rs/guide/getting-started/) and I'm trying to use it with [a JWT library](https://github.com/Keats/jsonwebtoken). They use different versions of the *ring* crate and I get an error during `cargo build`:

```
error: multiple packages link to native library `ring-asm`, but a native library can be linked only once

package `ring v0.12.1`
    ... which is depended on by `jsonwebtoken v4.0.1`
    ... which is depended on by `auther v0.1.0 (file:///home/drpytho/x/downloadble/auther)`
links to native library `ring-asm`

package `ring v0.11.0`
    ... which is depended on by `cookie v0.9.2`
    ... which is depended on by `rocket v0.3.6`
    ... which is depended on by `rocket_codegen v0.3.6`
    ... which is depended on by `auther v0.1.0 (file:///home/drpytho/x/downloadble/auther)`
also links to native library `ring-asm`
```

My Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "auther"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Name <Email@mail.se>"]

[dependencies]
rocket = "0.3.6"
rocket_codegen = "0.3.6"
jsonwebtoken = "4"
serde_derive = "1"
serde = "1"
```

I read that you are supposed to fix the mismatching dependencies in your Cargo file, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Related issues: https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/516 https://github.com/briansmith/ring/issues/575 https://github.com/briansmith/ring/issues/535

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to fix this by not transitively depending on different versions of crates that link to a native library.

There's no newer version of `rocket` available that depends on version `0.10` of `cookie`, which depends on `ring` `0.12`, so you'll need to downgrade `jsonwebtoken` to `2.0.3`.

You can work this out by checking the `crates.io` pages for the crates in question (like with [`jsonwebtoken`](https://crates.io/crates/jsonwebtoken)), going back through older versions, and looking to see what dependencies it needs.

Comment: Is there a way to force rocket to use a newer version (if I knew it would be  compatible)?

Comment: @drpytho: It might be possible with package replacement, but I don't know anything about that.  In general, you can't force a crate to use versions of dependencies it didn't specify.